# Display div after placeholder is removed during form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a div I would like to show when a customer enters into a form. I originally though a z-index solution would fix this but a display/show option seems better.

However, it doesn't seem to work. Can this be shortened or done in a better way?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input#poundprice").text().length > 0) {
        $('.pence-sign').show();
        //$('.pence-sign').addClass('display:block;');
    }                                           
    });
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evz6L3h5/)

Comment: As the user starts to input in the box or after the user submits the form

Comment: This checks if the input is populated *when the page loads*, but it never checks again. At which point would you like the `<div>` to be shown?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] **in your question**, not on jsFiddle. Second, you run your jQuery when the DOM is ready but should be running it whenever the input field is changed

Answer (score 3):

You need to be checking for when something is actually typed into the box. What you are currently doing only runs once when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#poundprice").on("change keydown paste",function(e) {
   $('.pence-sign').show();  
  });
  
  $("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.pence-sign {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23%;
  left: 30%;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: arial;
  display: none;
}

input, button {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="position:relative">
  <div class="poundinput" style="position:relative;">
    <p class="pence-sign">pence</p>
    <input id="poundprice" name="price" type="currency" placeholder="Enter p value" required="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not correct answer. On submit everything disappears.

Comment: You beat me to it! Though for user friendliness I would add "paste" to your event listener. Also try adding preventDefault so the form does not reset.

Comment: Updated with paste :)

Comment: This is almost there, however on certain sizes the pence value is in the same location as the placeholder. So when they click the input box to enter their value, I need the placeholder to vanish and pence value display, tried this ```input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting. Do you just want the placeholder text to say pence when they are focused on the input?